# Failed to execute 'quadraticCurveTo' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 4 arguments required, but only 0 present

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var data1 = [[1995,0],[1996,0],[1997,104],[1998,67]];

$("#flot-dashboard-chart").length && $.plot($("#flot-dashboard-chart"), [
                data2
            ],
                    {
                        series: {
                            lines: {
                                show: false,
                                fill: true
                            },
                            splines: {
                                show: true,
                                tension: 0.4,
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                fill: 0.4
                            },
                            points: {
                                radius: 0,
                                show: true
                            },
                            shadowSize: 2
                        },
                        grid: {
                            hoverable: true,
                            clickable: true,
                            tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            color: '#d5d5d5'
                        },
                        colors: ["#1ab394", "#1C84C6"],
                        xaxis:{
                        },
                        yaxis: {
//                            ticks: 4
                        },
                        tooltip: false
                    }
            );
```

This piece of code is working well but when I want to display month names on x-axis it gives by changing data to

```
var data2 = [["01-2016",48],["02-2016",48],["03-2016",53],["04-2016",37]];
```

Failed to execute 'quadraticCurveTo' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 4 arguments required, but only 0 present

The correct output when data is intergers

[image]

and when data is in strings

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure - did you change the data it's expecting and wondering why it doesn't work or does the library or whatever you're using accept an array consisting of a string and a number instead of two numbers?

Comment: Strings are not working and I am not getting any clue

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm talking about. Most likely it just accepts numbers. What are you using to draw the chart?

Comment: jquery library flot

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this tutorial site about Flot's data format: [http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/jquery-flot-data-format.html](http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/jquery-flot-data-format.html)